# Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit when installing ggpot2 package

Tags: r, ggplot2, installation, error-handling

I'm trying to install ggplot2 but I'm getting the following error:

```
> install.packages("ggplot2")
Retrieving 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.4.1.tar.gz' ...
    OK [downloaded 3 Mb in 0.2 secs]
Retrieving 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/vctrs_0.5.2.tar.gz' ...
    OK [downloaded 944.8 Kb in 0.1 secs]
Installing viridisLite [0.4.1] ...
    OK [linked cache]
Installing scales [1.2.1] ...
    OK [linked cache]
Installing vctrs [0.5.2] ...
    OK [built from source]
Moving vctrs [0.5.2] into the cache ...
    OK [moved to cache in 7.9 seconds]
Installing ggplot2 [3.4.1] ...
    OK [built from source]
Moving ggplot2 [3.4.1] into the cache ...
    OK [moved to cache in 12 seconds]
Error: C stack usage  15922816 is too close to the limit
```

I've tried reading up on this error message but what I've read is that the problem is [running a recursive function that runs too deep.](https://www.roelpeters.be/c-stack-error-limit/) How is this possible when installing a package? Is there a way around this?

Comment: If you navigate into renv directories you can see they are recursively soft-linked. Perhaps standalone install.packages is not aware of this

Comment: Answer yourself so can help someothers.

Answer (score 1):

I could fix it by using `renv::install("ggplot2")` since I'm working in an R environment. Still wondering if this is why the error occured at all (I've installed packages using the install.packages() command before within R environments. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using R 4.2.0 or newer, you can now attempt to catch certain stack overflow errors. For example:

```r
# NOTE: try adjusting this value depending on how
# nested the callstack appears to get
options(expressions = 200)

# R function that recurses infinitely
f <- function() {
  f()
}

# use withCallingHandlers() and print a stack trace on error
withCallingHandlers(
  f(),
  stackOverflowError = function(e) {
    # bump up expressions so we don't get another overflow
    options(expressions = 5000)

    # print a traceback
    print(rlang::trace_back())
  }
)
```

If you see this error again, you can try using this technique to see if you can get a stack trace -- depending on what you learn, you could file a bug report in the appropriate venue.